# Get and change the content of a list of objets using REST requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-hateoas

**Context**

I'm trying to create an API with SpringBoot, Hateoas, store data into H2 database and manage it with JPA.

I have 2 entities : `Mission` and `User`.

Several users are assigned to a mission. And users can be assigned to different missions.

I use `@ManyToMany` annotation to create an associative table.

**Objectives**

My goal is to create some requests as :

- (GET request) `IP/missions/123456/users` : Get all users assigned to mission `123456`
- (PUT request) `IP/missions/456789` : Assigned users to mission `456789`

**Code**

*Entities*

```
@Entity
public class Mission {

    @Id
    private String missionid;
    private String missionname;
    private Date start;
    private Date end;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "missions")
    @JoinTable(name = "missions_users",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "missionid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    )
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    private int status;

    public Mission() {
    }

    public Mission(String name, Date start, Date end) {
        this.namemission = name;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.status = 0;
    }


}

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private String userid;
    private String nameuser;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Mission> missions = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.nameuser = name;
    }
}
```

*Resources*

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "mission")
public interface MissionResource extends JpaRepository<Mission, String> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user")
public interface UserResource extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
}
```

*RestController*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/missions", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ExposesResourceFor(Mission.class)
public class MissionRepresentation {

    private final MissionResource missionResource;
    private final UserResource userResource;

    public MissionRepresentation(MissionResource missionResource, UserResource userResource) {
        this.missionResource = missionResource;
        this.userResource = userResource;
    }

    // mapping
}
```

*SQL script to fill database*

```
INSERT INTO mission (missionid, namemission, start, end, status) VALUES ('de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82', 'mission 1', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-13', 0)
INSERT INTO mission (missionid, namemission, start, end, status) VALUES ('425e7701-02c6-4de3-9333-a2459eece1c8', 'mission 2', '2019-02-10', '2019-02-15', 0)

INSERT INTO user (userid, nameuser) VALUES ('0dee5423-6bd9-4014-a690-0993b3cb5f3b', 'user 1')
INSERT INTO user (userid, nameuser) VALUES ('8e70ca41-8766-4188-bf37-3d9a0aae941d', 'user 2')
INSERT INTO user (userid, nameuser) VALUES ('75cb846a-3a7b-4116-8d8a-7778916dff8c', 'user 3')

INSERT INTO missions_users(missionid, userid) VALUES ('de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82', '0dee5423-6bd9-4014-a690-0993b3cb5f3b')
INSERT INTO missions_users(missionid, userid) VALUES ('de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82', '8e70ca41-8766-4188-bf37-3d9a0aae941d')
INSERT INTO missions_users(missionid, userid) VALUES ('425e7701-02c6-4de3-9333-a2459eece1c8', '8e70ca41-8766-4188-bf37-3d9a0aae941d')
INSERT INTO missions_users(missionid, userid) VALUES ('425e7701-02c6-4de3-9333-a2459eece1c8', '75cb846a-3a7b-4116-8d8a-7778916dff8c')
```

**Results**

Currently I try to do `GET` requests, but in the future I will have to do `POST`/`PUT`/... requests.

- *Result*

Request : `http://localhost:8082/mission/de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82`

```
{
    "missionid": "de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82",
    "namemission": "mission 1",
    "users": [
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "status": 0,
    "start": "2019-02-10T23:00:00.000+0000",
    "end": "2019-02-12T23:00:00.000+0000"
}
```

- *Result excepted*

Request : `http://localhost:8082/mission/de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82`

```
{
    "missionid": "de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82",
    "namemission": "mission 1",
    "users": [
        "user 1",
        "user 2"
    ],
    "status": 0,
    "start": "2019-02-10T23:00:00.000+0000",
    "end": "2019-02-12T23:00:00.000+0000"
}
```

Request : `http://localhost:8082/mission/de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82/users`

```
{
    "user 1",
    "user 2"
}
```

I don't know how to write my method to get only users names...

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{missionId}/users")
public ResponseEntity<?> getUsersByMission(@PathVariable("missionId") String missionId) {
    Mission mission = this.missionResource.findById(missionId).get();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(????, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

A solution is to use a list of String instead of a list of User?

**Conclusion**

Someone can help me to have expected results please? Thanks.

**EDIT 1: Result for @LppEdd answer**

```
[
    {
        "userid": "0dee5423-6bd9-4014-a690-0993b3cb5f3b",
        "nameuser": "user 1",
        "missions": []
    },
    {
        "userid": "8e70ca41-8766-4188-bf37-3d9a0aae941d",
        "nameuser": "user 2",
        "missions": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should pretty easy actually. You were almost there.
JPA will handle the `User` objects creation for you. Just expose your `Set<User>` to the outer world.

```
public class Mission {
   ...

   public Set<User> getUsers() {
      return users;
   }

   public void setUsers(final Set<User> users) {
      this.users = users;
   }

   ...
}
```

Inside your `@RestController`, you can then get a hold on, and return the `Set`.

```
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getUsersByMission(@PathVariable("missionId") String missionId) {
    final Optional<Mission> mission = this.missionResource.findById(missionId);

    if (mission.isEmpty()) {
       // Handle the "mission not found" case
    }

    final List<String> names = 
                  mission.get().getUsers()
                               .stream()
                               .map(user -> user.getNameUser())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(names);
}
```

To handle bidirectional `@ManyToMany` associations, you need to specify the `mappedBy` attribute, which will point to the  `Mission#users` field.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private Set<Mission> missions = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: I agree with you, but I will not have only name, I will have the full object (id and name) right?

Comment: @N.Lamblin yes, you'll get the entire User object. Do you need only the name?

Comment: I want to understand how works these tools so yes I try a lot of things. For example, get only names. Or define a chief of the mission and store it as String into Mission class : `private String chiefname;`. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: @N.Lamblin It's a broad topic. You can review it by reading the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/
In the meantime, you can map the User object to its name by using a Stream.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :). I updated my post with the result of your answer. Can you just tell me why `missions` is empty? Thanks.

Comment: @N.Lamblin I see the User object has a Set of "Tache" and not a Set of "Mission". That might be the cause.

Comment: Stupid mistake but it's not the reason. Thanks anyway.